# How can I read the selected item?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two select tags in my view.

```
<%= select("cod_resource", "description_resource", Resource.all.collect {|p| [ p.description_resource, p.cod_resource] }) %>

<%= select("cod_damage", "description_damage", Damage.find_all_by_cod_resource_id(0).collect {|p| [ p.description_damage, p.cod_damage] }) %>
```

I want to update the value in the second item tag when the user selects the value in the first item tag.

I edit my code in this mode:

```
  <select id="resource" data-theme="c" onchange="changeValue(this)">
    <%= Resource.find(:all).each do |r| %>
        <option value="<%= r.cod_resource %>">
          <%= r.description_resource %>
        </option>
    <% end %>
  </select>

  <select id="damage" data-theme="c">
    <%= Damage.find_all_by_cod_resource_id(1).each do |r| %>
        <option value="<%= r.cod_damage %>">
          <%= r.description_damage %>
        </option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
```

and I add this script in application.html.erb:

```
function changeValue(obj){
   $("#damage").append("<option>Hello</option>");
}
```

it work, but if i edit in this mode

```
  function changeValue(obj){
        <%= Damage.find_all_by_cod_resource_id(1).each do |r| %>
      $("#damage").append(" <option value='<%= r.cod_damage %>''><%= r.description_damage %></option>");
      <% end %>
  }
```

it not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fire ajax request to update second select box.
Following article help you to do this http://paramitech.com/dynamically-udating-select-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices. One that you can try is using [.appen()](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Here a example

http://jsbin.com/eguzeb/1/edit

Note: You have to use Ajax to do archive what you need.

Comment: i tried this solution  but i have some problem when i insert ruby code inner  the changeValue(obj) function.

Comment: No, you cannot insert another thing that javascript code. You have to make a ajax request to the server. See here in the comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735049/how-can-i-make-options-of-once-select-list-depended-on-another#comment24099860_16735049

Answer (score 0):

Inspect select tag  in your browser, Rails will give specified id or class in the form tag

```
<%= select("cod_resource", "description_resource", Resource.all.collect {|p| [ p.description_resource, p.cod_resource] }) %>

<%= select("cod_damage", "description_damage", Damage.find_all_by_cod_resource_id(0).collect {|p| [ p.description_damage, p.cod_damage] }) %>
```

Find id or class name for your select tag and try this code

```
  $('first_select_tag_id/class').change(function(){
      alert($('this').val());
    }

    $('second_select_tag_id/class').change(function(){
      alert($('this').val());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I resolved my problem with ajax request:

This is my ajax request:

```
<script>

      function changeValue(obj){
          resource_id = $("#resource").val();
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "/reports/",
              data: "resource_id="+resource_id,
              success: function(html){
                  var part= $("<div/>").append(html).find('#damage_list').html();
                  $("#damage_list").html(part);
              }
          });
       }

  </script>
```

and this is the code of html part

```
      <select id="resource" data-theme="c" onchange="changeValue(this)">
        <%= Resource.find(:all).each do |r| %>
            <option value="<%= r.cod_resource %>">
              <%= r.description_resource %>
            </option>
        <% end %>
      </select>

      <!-- Home -->
      <div id="damage_list">
        <select id="damage" data-theme="c">
          <%= Damage.find_all_by_cod_resource_id(params[:resource_id]).each do |r| %>
              <option value="<%= r.cod_damage %>">
                <%= r.description_damage %>
              </option>
          <% end %>
        </select>
      </div>
```

It is work!!!
There is  small problem, it is not reload the  JQuery Mobile style in the select box.
I searched this problem but all solutions that i found don't work.